# Correctly measure CPU usage with HyperThreading?

Tags: c++, winapi, cpu-usage

I know there are several answers here on SO on how to measure CPU usage with either of two approaches:

- By using the performance counters (PDH API)
- By using [GetProcessTimes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx) and dividing that against either wall time or times from [GetSystemTimes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx)

For some days now I am miserably failing to perform CPU usage measurements of my program with either of these - with both mechanisms I get a CPU usage that is smaller than displayed in Task Manager or Process Explorer. Is there some magic how these tools do this and is this related to HyperThreading being enabled? I will perform my tests on a CPU without HyperThreding but if anyone can point out what am I missing here I would be very thankful.

To illustrate what I have tried, here is the code that does PDH based measruements:

```
class CCpuUsageMonitor
{
public:
    CCpuUsageMonitor(const wchar_t* pProcessName)
    {

        GetSystemInfo(&m_SystemInfo);
        auto nStatus = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, NULL, &m_hPdhQuery);
        _ASSERT(nStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        nStatus = PdhAddCounter(m_hPdhQuery, L"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", NULL, &m_hPdhCpuUsageCounter);
        _ASSERT(nStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        wchar_t pCounterPath[PDH_MAX_COUNTER_PATH];
        StringCbPrintf(pCounterPath, PDH_MAX_COUNTER_PATH, L"\\Process(%s)\\%% Processor Time", pProcessName);
        nStatus = PdhAddCounter(m_hPdhQuery, pCounterPath, NULL, &m_hPhdProcessCpuUsageCounter);
        _ASSERT(nStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);
    }

    ~CCpuUsageMonitor()
    {
        PdhCloseQuery(&m_hPdhQuery);
    }

    void CollectSample()
    {
        auto nStatus = PdhCollectQueryData(m_hPdhQuery);
        _ASSERT(nStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);
    }

    double GetCpuUsage()
    {
        DWORD nType;
        PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE CounterValue;
        auto nStatus = PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(m_hPdhCpuUsageCounter, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE | PDH_FMT_NOCAP100, &nType, &CounterValue);
        _ASSERT(nStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        return CounterValue.doubleValue;
    }

    double GetProcessCpuUsage()
    {
        DWORD nType;
        PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE CounterValue;
        auto nStatus = PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(m_hPhdProcessCpuUsageCounter, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE | PDH_FMT_NOCAP100, &nType, &CounterValue);
        _ASSERT(nStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        return CounterValue.doubleValue / m_SystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
    }

private:
    SYSTEM_INFO m_SystemInfo;
    HANDLE m_hPdhQuery;
    HANDLE m_hPdhCpuUsageCounter;
    HANDLE m_hPhdProcessCpuUsageCounter;
};
```

With the second approach I basically take two snapshots of process times via [GetProcessTimes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx) before and after my code runs, substract and divide against wall time multiplied by the number of processors.

Comment: How much difference do you get? Sampling error, or "completely different"?

Comment: @MatsPetersson a constanly lower measurement by a factor of around 1.5 to 2. The test code is doing spurious wakeups from a timer and working for short regular periods of time. Maybe the tools actually sample at high time interval and are wrong? I'll try to make a complete example.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: Hey, I'm curious if you got it figured out? I'm dealing with the same issue. Want to exchange ideas if you're still on it?

Comment: @c00000fd If honestly this was very long age, I don't remember if I came to a fix or no. This code was basically to test H.264 encoding for a paper in the university but I do not remember if I discarded the CPU measurements in the end or no. The code is available at https://github.com/rubu/AIEEE2015/blob/master/Shared/TestRun.hpp, so you can simply try if it works better than what is pasted here or has the same issue:D Sorry for that:)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few links I've used in the past and a good article on why GetThreadTimes is wrong (I wouldn't use it as a reliable source of data):

http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=28

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397(VS.85).aspx

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/win32-performance-measurement-options/184416651

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394279(VS.85).aspx

You seem well on your way and knowledgeable those links should get you going in the right direction at least.

Answer (score 1):

From [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/cpu-usage-exceeds-100):

> Starting with Windows 8, a change was made to the way that Task Manager and Performance Monitor report CPU utilization...
>
> This change affects the way that CPU utilization is computed. The values in Task Manager now correspond to the **Processor Information\% Processor Utility** and **Processor Information\% Privileged Utility** performance counters, not to the **Processor Information\% Processor Time** and **Processor Information\% Privileged Time** counters as in Windows 7.

Your code will work as written other than the change in which counters you are querying.  You are using the **Processor** counters; you should switch to **Processor Information** enabled in Windows 8; and also use the "Utility" versions of the counters.

If you query the formatted value as you currently do, you'll get the same number displayed on the Task manager with 1-second polling.

If you want to do calculations over longer intervals, you can query the raw value; the numbers into a `PDH_RAW_COUNTER` structure instead of your current `PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE`.  The values used to calculate the usage for the numerator are in the `PDH_RAW_COUNTER` structure's `FirstValue`, and the "base" values for the denominator are in `SecondValue`.